# php preg_replace all characters after whitespace in each line

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, whitespace

I have a script that outputs an array that, when each item in the array is printed out, gives me

```
https://media.com/2db93b9.jpg Ann
https://media.com/3198676.jpg Lin
https://media.com/ David
https://media.com/0f48c22.jpg Ulrich
https://media.com/135f3b7.jpg David
```

I am trying to drop the space, and everything else after it with the following preg_replace

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $row = preg_replace("[\\ ].*", "", $row);
    echo $row . '<br />';
}
```

According to http://regexr.com, that pattern of mine should work. But when I have tried both `/[\\ ].*/g` and `[\\ ].*`. Neither works. It says php met an unknown modifier. Obviously, I'm no regular expressions expert, and I would love any kind of help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$row = preg_replace('/ .*$/', "", $row);
```

Or:

```
$row = preg_replace('/\s.*$/', "", $row);
```

- Regex needs a delimiter in PHP
- Correct regex should a space and **everything** thereafter using `.*$`
- `\s` matches space OR tab or newline

Comment: Ah, that's it. However, I was mistaken in my assumption that it was a whitespace that were separating the URL and the name. It turns out that it's either a whitespace AND a line-break, or just a line-break. Only that when printed in browser, it looks like a whitespace. How do I manage that?

Comment: Just use: `$row = preg_replace('/\s.*$/', "", $row);` where `\s` will match **space OR tab or newline**